# Match the first characters of easyautocomplete

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete

I'm using [easyautocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/) but I notice that isn't maching well, is not matching the first characters, instead is just matching the ones in the end. In my case I'm looking for  "FR Ryanair", so I first inserted "FR", but is not searching by the first 2 characters. Can someone explain what is wrong? I leave above a link example.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRjNJP

And source code:

```
var options = {
    url: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cdLxcejibm?indent=2",

    getValue: "label",

    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        },

    }
};

$("#provider-json").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the match method to do whatever you want. Take a look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObZKZQ.

```
 method: function(element, phrase) {
    if(phrase.length < 2) return false;
    if(phrase.length == 2){
      return element.split(" ")[0] === phrase;
    }
    if (element.search(phrase) > -1){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jordan, one last question, i just tried to search for example by "Ryanair" but it doesnt show any results, what is missing?

Comment: Well, that was the behavior it had before, right? Which do you want?

Comment: Basically in the label there is for example "FR Ryanair", "FR" is the airline code, and than it shows "Ryanair" that is the name of the airline, sometimes there are users that search for the airline code or by the name of the airline, what i want is to be able the user search for code or name and appear the given result, just a note, the flight codes are always 2 characters (letters or numbers).

Comment: Will all your data be encoded as: <Flight Code>[space]<Airline name>?

Comment: hello, yes it will.

Comment: doesnt easyautocomplete support adding a selec scroll with the autocomplete?

Comment: Hello jordan, is there a method a way of detecting when there is only one result? For example imagine that when i search for a word, appears only one result, in this case i would like to insert this result automatclly on the input without click or selecting with the mouse. Is it possible?